# Riverpod StreamProvider access the stream

Tags: dart, riverpod

I am using socket_client_io and Riverpod. Socket client uses events for updates which I want to propagate in a StreamProvider.

What I currently have is the following. It gets the job done but... I would like to write directly to the stream within StreamProvider so I don't need to create an extra stream just to go from events to yield.

```dart
final downloadProgressProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Progress>((ref) async* {
  // open socketio
  final Server host = ref.read(configProvider).talkServer;
  final String jwt = ref.read(userProvider).jwt;

  IO.Socket _socket = IO.io('${host.uri.toString()}/?token=$jwt', IO.OptionBuilder()
      .setTransports(['websocket'])
      .build()
  );

  StreamController<Progress> _stream = StreamController<Progress>();
  
  ref.onDispose(() {
    // close socketio
    _stream.close();
    _stream = null;
    _socket.dispose();
    _socket = null;
  });

  _socket.on('download-update', (message) {
    print('download-update incoming');
    _stream.add(Progress.fromJson(json.decode(message)))

  });

  await for (final value in _stream.stream) {
    yield value;
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried just "yield* _stream.stream" in place of your loop?

Comment: I am using the same setup, but it is not clear for me why you say there are two streams here, the example on documentation uses `WebsocketClient`, from Flutter, which already uses a stream controller i guess.

Comment: Where do you connect the socket io client?

Comment: have you solved this ? \